# VBA displaying unique values in list

Tags: excel, vba

The following code filters unique values from a column. I am trying to display the output in the console, however, I get a "Subscript out of range" error. Is the array output from the function being passed into the variable correctly? If not, what is the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Member() As String

Member = UnqiueMembers() 
Debug.Print Member(1)

End Sub
```

---

```
' get unique members from input data
Public Function UnqiueMembers() As String()

Const inputSheetName = "Input Data"
Const inputRange = "A3:A9"

Dim productWS As Worksheet
Dim uniqueList() As String 'dyanmic array
Dim productsList As Range
Dim anyProduct
Dim LC As Integer

ReDim uniqueList(1 To 1)
Set productWS = Worksheets(inputSheetName)
'Set outputWS = Worksheets(outputSheetName)
Set productsList = productWS.Range(inputRange)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each anyProduct In productsList
  If Not IsEmpty(anyProduct) Then
    If Trim(anyProduct) <> "" Then
      For LC = LBound(uniqueList) To UBound(uniqueList)
        If Trim(anyProduct) = uniqueList(LC) Then
          Exit For ' found match, exit
        End If
      Next
      If LC > UBound(uniqueList) Then
        'new item, add it
        uniqueList(UBound(uniqueList)) = Trim(anyProduct)
        'make room for another
        ReDim Preserve uniqueList(1 To UBound(uniqueList) + 1)
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next ' end anyProduct loop
If UBound(uniqueList) > 1 Then
  'remove empty element
  ReDim Preserve uniqueList(1 To UBound(uniqueList) - 1)
End If


UniqueMembers = uniqueList()

End Function
```

Comment: simply `UniqueMembers = uniqueList` without brackets will do the trick ;)

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still getting the error

Comment: Do you have worksheet named **Input Data** in your workbook?

Comment: i have tested it, and there was no error... the only reason which is left, is MutjayLee's suggestion.

Comment: yes i definitely have the right worksheet. The function behaves correctly because I printed the contents of 'uniquelist' and it gave the correct results. For some reason the array isnt passing into the Member variable

Comment: What line of code is giving you the error?

Comment: Debug.Print Member(1)

Answer (score 1):

Another `Option Explicit` candidate: function name is `UnqiueMembers` but you are returning a value by `UniqueMembers = uniqueList()`

Those two names are not the same ;-(

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly.  If all you want this a unique list.  Use the Collection.  and reject dups.

```
Dim t As Collection

Set t = New Collection
Dim t As Collection
Set t = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
t.Add "product name", "product name"
t.Add "product name", "product name"
t.Add "product name", "product name"
t.Add "product name", "product name"
t.Add "product name", "product name"
t.Add "product name", "product name"

On Error GoTo 0
```

the collection will not allow you to add any duplicate values.  t will automatically become unique.